How is mechanical energy conserved in inclined plane-block system?
This is a rather standard problem where there is an inclined plane (of mass M) on a frictionless horizontal surface and a block (of mass m) slides on it. The problem asks us to calculate the speeds of both the plane and block once the block descends to the horizontal surface.
It is solved via Linear Momentum Conservation theorem (in the x-axis) and Mechanical Energy Conservation theorem.
I am confused why is the latter theorem applicable here. Mechanical energy is conserved when there is no work done by nonconservative forces. When we consider plane and block to be a system, then there are 3 external forces : mg, Mg and N (normal applied by horizontal surface on plane). mg and Mg are conservative forces but N is not. And because the centre of mass of the system goes downwards, N does negative work on the system (not 0). So, how is the Mechanical Energy conserved in this case?

Energy overall is conserved, not just "mechanical" energy (which I presume you mean kinetic energy). By moving down, gravitational potential energy is converted into kinetic energy.

@JonCuster By Mechanical Energy, I mean the sum total of Kinetic and Potential Energies. I know overall energy is conserved. I am confused why is mechanical energy conserved.

“It is solved via Linear Momentum Conservation theorem (in the y-axis)” Linear momentum’s not conserved in the $y$ (vertical) axis unless you include the Earth in your system.

@BobD Sorry, edited it.

@JonCuster It's pretty standard to call the sum of kinetic and potential energies "mechanical energy"

System block and plane.
The block loses gravitational potential energy and the block and plane gain an equal amount of kinetic energy as the are no dissipative forces, eg friction.
Two forces on the block:
1 External gravitational force, $mg$, downwards due to attraction of Earth
2 Internal normal force on slope of plane due to the plane.
Positive work done by force 1 is $mgh$ where $h$ is the vertical drop of the centre of mass of the block.
Negative work is done by force 2 as there is a displacement of the force along the line of action of this force in the opposite direction to the force.
Three forces on the block:
3 External gravitational force, $Mg$, downwards due to attraction of Earth
4 Internal normal force on slope of plane due to the block - equal magnitude opposite direction to force 2 (N3L)
5 External normal force on base of plane due to the surface.
No work is done by forces 3 as the centre of mass of the plane does not move vertically.
Positive work is done by force 4 as there is a displacement of the force along the line of action of this force in the direction of the force.
No work is done by force 5 as the displacement of the force is perpendicular to the direction of the force.
The negative work done by internal normal force 2 plus the positive work done by internal normal force 4 is equal to the net work done by the two internal normal forces and is zero, as shown below.

At time $t$ the block is at position $A$ on the plane and at some later time $t+\delta t$ the block is at position $B$ on the plane.
The red vectors shown the normal force on the block due to the plane at the s(tart) and f(inish) and the blue vectors shown the same for the normal force on the plane due to the block.
For both normal forces the displacement of the forces along their line of action is $\delta s$.
The work done by the normal force on the block is $N_{\rm bp}\times(-\delta s)$ and the work done by the normal force on the plane is $N_{\rm pb}\times(+\delta s)$.
As the normal forces have the same magnitude the net work done by the two normal forces is zero.

The incline gains kinetic energy, so at least one force acting on it must do work on it

@BioPhysicist Many thanks for pointing out my error which I hope I have now corrected.

Force 2 does negative work :) But I posted an answer to clarify

@BioPhysicist Thanks again!


Mechanical energy is conserved when there is no work done by
nonconservative forces.

Mechanical energy is conserved when there is no work done by dissipative forces. However, while all dissipative forces, such as friction and air resistance/drag, are nonconservative, not all nonconservative forces, such as simple push-pull forces, are dissipative. See also the answer here:  What is the difference between Non-Conservative and Dissipative?

So normal force is a non dissipative nonconservative force?

Yes.
The normal force is a push-pull force, specifically the component of a push pull force acting normal (perpendicular) to the surface. Thus it's a non-conservative force.
Although the kinetic friction force is proportional to the magnitude of the normal force, it is the kinetic friction force in the direction of displacement parallel to the surface that does dissipative work. Since the normal force is perpendicular to that direction, it doesn’t do work in that direction.
Thus the normal force is a non-conservative non-dissipative force.
Hope this helps.

So normal force is a non dissipative nonconservative force? Does that when I am allowed to use Mechanical Energy Conservation in presence of normal force everytime?

@PrasoonJha - force has to work over a distance to change energy. Standing still on the ground you experience a normal force due to gravity. But you do not move up or down, so your energy does not change. The same holds true for the block - there is a normal force but the blocks do not move along that direction so the normal force does not change the energy of the system.

@JonCuster I believe the OP is thinking about the components of the normal forces that do work internal to the system.

@BobD - could well be. Certainly better suited to a one-on-one discussion with the prof, TA, or tutor.

@JonCuster I understand that the plane is not moving but if we consider both inclined plane and block to be a system then the whole system does move downwards (as its centre of mass moves downwards). And as normal is also applied in the vertical direction, there must be negative work done by normal.

@PrasoonJha “I understand that the plane is not moving”.  The plane is moving

@PrasoonJha see update to my answer

@BobD Sorry, I misworded it. I meant to say that plane is not moving in vertical direction.

@PrasoonJha got it. No problem

The interaction between the block and incline does no work overall. It does positive work on the incline and negative work on the block, but the combined work by the interaction has to be 0 since each force follows the same point of contact with the same magnitude but points in opposite directions.
Therefore, the only relevant net work on the system here is that done by gravity on the block, which is already accounted for in the total mechanical energy.
